# Was this character's death necessary?

Tags: fear-the-walking-dead

In the latest episode of *Fear the Walking Dead*

> Rufus dies after he is put down because he was bitten by a walker.

Canonically animals are immune to the virus. While medicine and medical supplies might be required to treat injuries we know that those supplies have been found when needed in the past.

> So if he was not in threat of turning or getting sick and dying why did they kill him so quickly? Was his death unnecessary?

Comment: He may not have become a zombie dog but the chance of rabies or something similar is incredibly high given the *filthy* nature of bites especially from zombies. Granted they were a bit quick but it's more likely this is just for dramatic purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animals may be immune to zombification, but that does not make them immune against every possible infection or disease.

Euthanizing him may simply have been an act of kindness, as opposed to it being done to prevent him from becoming a walker.